# Why I don't want to embed this loop in my insertion sort?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I have a class and right now we are doing insertion sort. I think my code worked properly but my professor said not to embed one of my loops (it shifts the values in my array over) and that it should be done while "searching".

```
public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
    int n = array.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int nextIndex = i;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if(array[nextIndex] < array[j]) {
                int temp = array[nextIndex];
                // ********************************
                for(int k = i; k > j; k--) { 
                    array[k]=array[k-1];
                }
                // ********************************
                array[j]=temp;
                j = i
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: A note on your code: You don’t seem to manipulate `nextIndex` anywhere. Why not use `i` instead, or name `i` `nextIndex`?  — Instead of setting a loop’s condition (more or less) explicitly to false (`j=i`), it is common to terminate it by using the `break` statement. It exits the current loop prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your professor meant is this: You are currently looking through the sorted part of your array [0..i] from bottom to top to find the position at which the new element should be inserted. *Afterwards* you move through your array from top to bottom to shift the new element to the right position.

Instead, you could just move the new element through the element and *simultaneously* look for the right position, similar to Bubblesort, if you know the algorithm. This saves you this `for`-loop your prof marked.